# How can I assign a default value to a structure in a C++ function?

Tags: c++, function, struct

I have a structure:

```
typedef struct {
   double x,y,z;
} XYZ;
```

I want to define a function like this:

```
double CalcDisparity(XYZ objposition, 
                     XYZ eyeposition, 
                     double InterOccularDistance = 65.0)
```

But I can't seem to find a way to assign a default value to eyeposition.  How can I do this in C++?

Comment: @drknexus, a struct in C++ is exactly the same as a class, except that it's members are public by default whereas a class members are private by default.  That's it.  Structs can have constructors, destructors, methods, basically everything a class has.  Now if you're talking about C then they're different again, so you need to be clear as to which language you're talking about

Comment: It's C++, so I've edited the question and tags to remove C from the question.

Comment: Default values for arguments does not work in C at all.  Don't confuse C with C++, they are very different.

Comment: @diverscuba23: I think this can only be C++, because C doesn't have default arguments.

Comment: It is C++ sorry.  Frankly I stumble around in my programming so the distinctions between the languages are lost on me.

Comment: @Dan Yeah, I was just wondering to make sure I fully understood the question. I have just assumed parts like that before and gave wrong information to the question being asked.... got real cautious after that....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's

```
struct XYZ{
    XYZ( double _x, double _y, double _z ) : x(_x), y(_y),z(_z){}
    XYZ() : x(0.0), y(42.0), z(0.0){}

    double x, y, z;
};
```

so that I now have a default constructor.  Then you call it like this:

```
double CalcDisparity( XYZ objposition = XYZ(),
                      XYZ eyeposition = XYZ(),
                      double interOccularDistance = 65.0 )
```

But there's one small trick: you can't do a default value for the 1st and 3rd arguments only.  One more thing: C is a language, C++ is another language.

Comment: You can if you define additional constructors, eg: `struct XYZ { XYZ(double _x, double _z) : x(_x), y(42.0), z(_z) };  double CalcDisparity( XYZ objposition = XYZ(), XYZ eyeposition = XYZ(1.0, 2.0), double interOccularDistance = 65.0 );`

Answer (score 2):

In `C`, function arguments cannot have default values (don't know about `C++`).

What you can do, in `C`, is pass a (somehow) invalid value, check for that invalid value and use another instead.

```
int foo(int n) {
  if (n == -1) { /* -1 is invalid */
    n = 42;      /* use 42 instead */
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: When this answer was given, the question was tagged 'C'; the tag has since been removed because C does not support default values for arguments.

Comment: C++ does support default values.

Answer (score 1):

1. You could write a factory function for creating XYZ objects, and call the function as the default value.
2. You could make NULL the default value, and then check in the function if the argument is NULL, creating a default XYZ if it is.
3. Create a global XYZ object and assign it as the default.
4. If you don't mind using C++ instead of pure C, make XYZ a class with a constructor.

Those are all ways that will compile and work, but some might not be good coding practices.

Comment: if he's using C++ then he can leave it as a struct, but give it a constructor

Answer (score -1):

You can combine the last solution with a part of my solution. You implement a counter of instances. If this counter is 0 you initialize value. But the counter never reaches anything else than 0...

Maybe it helps.