# Pass a struct as formal parameter when creating object

Tags: c++, qt

.h:

```
class Note : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Note(Traymenu *trayMenuIn, int i = 0, QWidget *parent = 0);
```

.cpp:

```
Note::Note(Traymenu *trayMenuIn, int i, QWidget *parent) :
```

I am creating a new Note by this:

```
void Traymenu::newNote(){
    QSharedPointer<Note> note(new Note(this));
    m_noteList << note;
```

What do I have to write instead of `int i = 0` and `int i`, if I want to pass a `struct`?

Before creating the note, I am building a structure like

```
struct properties {
     std::string title;
     int posX, posY;
}noteProp;

noteProp.title="name";
```

I tried passing that structure with `struct properties notePropIn = 0` in the prototype, but I get the error `cannot convert int 0 to struct`. I need the 0 because this parameter is only used if a note gets loaded, not created the 1st time.
Then a new note should be created with

```
void Traymenu::newNote(){
    QSharedPointer<Note> note(new Note(this, noteProp));
    m_noteList << note;
```

Comment: There's a previous post about [Passing structs to functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181765/passing-structs-to-functions) Hopefully that's useful.

Comment: I did non of those mentioned mistakes.

Comment: It contains examples of passing a struct to a function in the answers to the post. Where you have "struct properties notePropIn = 0" try just "properties notePropIn"

Comment: the `struct` is optional but not bad, as I have read there. If I remove the `= 0`, I would have to pass a structure even if I did not need it...

Comment: @user2366975 So is your question actually, how to declare a default value for an object parameter?

Comment: both passing and setting by default if not used...

Comment: You can give your struct definition a constructor to set your default parameters, then when you don't want to supply an actual struct, you can just pass "properties()" which will pass the default. Here's what I think you're after [assigning default to struct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688091/how-can-i-assign-a-default-value-to-a-structure-in-a-c-function).

Comment: that's absolute overkill. Going to see after overloading...

Comment: You can define multiple constructors, one with your struct, one without if you like

Comment: Ye I am trying hat. Somehow I don't get it either. Error `<name of struct> has incomplete type`