# Left and Right operand of comma operator has no effect (Warning)

Tags: c++, class, constructor, warnings, comma-operator

I'm getting a warning in my constructor in my class, and I've never seen it before. This is what my constructor looks like.

```
    Account(std::string n = "NULL", std::string i = "0", Stats s = (0,0,1) ) 
        : name(n), id(i), stat(s) {}
```

If I remove any of these commas it results in a compile error, no? 
Is this warning incorrect, or is there something I can change to fix it?

Comment: I could help if you actually **copy** the warning.

Comment: I wrote the warning in the title, omitting [-Wunused-value]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is this: `(0,0,1)`.

That is parentheses around the expression `0,0,1`, which evaluates to `1`. (The comma operator is an infix operator that evaluates the first and second expression and returns the second. In this case, you have two such operators.)

I don't know what you wanted there, but I'm guessing that isn't it.

---

EDIT: It seems you want `Stats s(0,0,1)`.

Comment: That's another constructor that consists of Stats(int, int, int);
I used it to separate initializing values.

Comment: I just re-read the question and realized I gave you a wrong suggestion. That syntax cannot be used for defaulted parameters... I'm sorry... xD

Answer (score 3):

The problem is most likely in that part `Stats s = (0,0,1)`. C++ sees this as a sequence of expression to be computed while keeping only the last value. It returns 1. You probably mean

```
Stats s = Stats(0,0,1)
```

which works if your stats structure have such a constructor. Note that in C++11 you have this shorter syntax:

```
Stats s = {0,0,1}
```

Comment: I am not sure if this works. You need to use regular parentheses while initializing structs. Curly braces are used for initializing arrays.

Comment: @EnginKayraklioglu No, that is wrong. It was right, in some contexts (not this one), before C++11.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks for explanation. Maybe it is legitimate even in older versions, I just never encountered this.

Comment: @EnginKayraklioglu Pre-C++11, it depends on whether `Stats` is an *aggregate*.

Comment: Yeah, the braces get rid of that warning. But they won't work if using pre c++11.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is to give a default value to function argument which is a struct, and I think it was discussed here [How can I assign a default value to a structure in a C++ function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688091/how-can-i-assign-a-default-value-to-a-structure-in-a-c-function)